# A small question about integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

so I didn't find an answer online, so I would like to ask which answer is correct:

$$\int_{-4}^4 x^3 \,dx  = 0 $$

or

$$\int_{-4}^4 x^3 \,dx  = 64 $$

Thank you!

Comment: **Hint:** $x^3$ is odd.

Comment: Yea, that's why I'm asking it, however I doubt the area from -4 to 0 "cancels" the area from 0 to 4, but not sure, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$f(x)=x^3$ is an odd function. This means that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and we have:

$$
\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=\int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx+\int_{0}^a f(x)dx=\int_{0}^a f(-x)dx+\int_{0}^a f(x)dx=-\int_{0}^a f(x)dx+\int_{0}^a f(x)dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(-x)=-f(x)$

$$
\int_{0}^{4}f\left(x\right)\text{d}x\underset{x \rightarrow -x}{=}\int_{0}^{-4}f\left(-x\right)\left(-\text{d}x\right)=-\int_{-4}^{0}f\left(x\right)\text{d}x
$$
So it's null summung over $-4$ to $4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $F(x)=\frac14 x^4$, then $\int_{-4}^4 x^3 dx =F(4)-F(-4)=4^3-4^3=0$.